# Linking GA4 & Google Ads

Tags: analytics, ads, google-analytics-4

I have recently upgraded my Universal Analytics (UA) property to the new Google Analytics 4 (GA4) property. However, I'm facing an issue while attempting to establish a link between the GA4 property and my Google Ads account. The challenge lies in the fact that the only GA property that appears in the Ads Link Settings is the old UA property, which is disabled.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on this.

I have made multiple attempts to rectify this situation, including attempting to link the GA4 property to Ads directly from GA4 and even removing the existing link from the Ads side, but regrettably, none of these actions have yielded any positive results. The issue remains unresolved.